# Не скрывать элементы управления ExoPlayer

Tags: android, exoplayer

При старте проигрывания через несколько сек. элементы управления пропадают и черный фон становится, если нажать на плеер опять появляются. Как сделать чтобы элементы вообще всегда отображались?